# Combine two lists into a formatted string in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I need to create a string parameter to pass to the aws-cli via local-exec so need to combine two lists from the remote state into the required format, cannot think of a good way to do this using the inbuilt interpolation functions.

Required string format

```
"SubnetId=subnet-x,Ip=ip_x SubnetId=subnet--y,Ip=ip_y SubnetId=subnet-z,Ip=ip_z"
```

We have the subnets and corresponding cidrs in two separate lists.

```
["subnet-x","subnet-y","subnet-z"]
["cidr-x","cidr-y","cidr-z"]
```

Was thinking I could use the cidrhost function to obtain the IPs but cannot see a way to format the two lists into the one string.

Comment: How exact does that output need to be? Are you passing that into something specific?

Comment: Also how do you intend to go from `cidr_x` to `ip_x`?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I think he was going to try to use the `cidrhost` function to convert from `cidr_x` to `ip_x`.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR pretty as the example as this is what the aws-cli expects as the input.

Comment: @MattSchuchard yes that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the guys at work came up with this,

```
 variable "subnet_ids" {
   default = ["subnet-345325", "subnet-345243", "subnet-345234"]
 }

 variable "cidrs" {
   default = ["10.0.0.0/24", "10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/23"]
 }

 resource "null_resource" "subnet_strings_option_one" {
   count = "${length(var.subnet_ids)}"

   triggers {
     value = "SubnetId=${var.subnet_ids[count.index]},Ip=${cidrhost(var.cidrs[count.index],11)}"
   }
 }

 output "subnet_strings_option_one" {
   value = "${join("",null_resource.subnet_strings_option_one.*.triggers.value)}"
 }
```

This gives the following output

```
    null_resource.subnet_strings_option_one[1]: Creating...
      triggers.%:     "" => "1"
      triggers.value: "" => "SubnetId=subnet-345243,Ip=10.0.1.11"
    null_resource.subnet_strings_option_one[2]: Creating...
      triggers.%:     "" => "1"
      triggers.value: "" => "SubnetId=subnet-345234,Ip=10.0.2.11"
    null_resource.subnet_strings_option_one[0]: Creating...
      triggers.%:     "" => "1"
      triggers.value: "" => "SubnetId=subnet-345325,Ip=10.0.0.11"
    null_resource.subnet_strings_option_one[2]: Creation complete after 0s (ID: 852839482792384695)
    null_resource.subnet_strings_option_one[1]: Creation complete after 0s (ID: 5439264637705543321)
    null_resource.subnet_strings_option_one[0]: Creation complete after 0s (ID: 1054498808481879719)

    Apply complete! Resources: 3 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

    Outputs:

    subnet_strings_option_one = SubnetId=subnet-345325,Ip=10.0.0.11 SubnetId=subnet-345243,Ip=10.0.1.11 SubnetId=subnet-345234,Ip=10.0.2.11
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using [formatlist](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#formatlist-format-args-) followed by [join](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#join-delim-list-).

```
locals {
   # this should give you 
   formatted_list = "${formatlist("SubnetId=%s,Ip=%s", var.subnet_list, var.cidrs_list}"

   # combine the formatted list of parameter together using join
   cli_parameter = "${join(" ", locals.formatted_list)}"
}
```

EDIT: You will need to use a `null_resource` to convert the CIDRs to IP Addresses like in the other answer. Then you can just build the `formatted_list` and `cli_parameter` similar to before.

```
locals {
   subnet_list = ["subnet-x","subnet-y","subnet-z"]
   cidr_list = ["cidr-x","cidr-y","cidr-z"]

   # this should give you 
   formatted_list = "${formatlist("SubnetId=%s,Ip=%s", var.subnet_list, null_resource.cidr_host_convert.*.triggers.value)}"

   # combine the formatted list of parameter together using join
   cli_parameter = "${join(" ", locals.formatted_list)}"
}

resource "null_resource" "cidr_host_convert" {
   count = "${length(locals.cidr_list}"

   trigger = {
      # for each CIDR, get the first IP Address in it. You may need to manage
      # the index value to prevent overlap
      desired_ips = "${cidrhost(locals.cidr_list[count.index], 1)}"
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks good, how would you include the call to cidrhost to get the desired IP from the CIDR?

Comment: You will need to layer the `null resource` with the formatting to build the variables. Terraform will figure out the dependencies and run the `null_resource` before generating the `formatted_list` and `cli_parameter` variables.